# PropertyGrid - get chosen bitmap's file path

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, bitmap, propertygrid

I set a `PropertyGrid`'s `SelectedObject` to an object with a `Bitmap` property:

```
public class Obj
{   
    private Bitmap myimage;
    [Category("Main Category")]
    [Description("Your favorite image")]
    public Bitmap MyImage
    {
        get { return myimage; }
        set
        {
            myimage = value;
        }
    }
}
```

This automatically shows the property in the `PropertyGrid` with a little button that the user can click on to select the image. How can I get the file path of this image?

(Also, is there any way I can override the dialog box that pops up and put my own one in? I know this is a separate question so I'll probably post it separately.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I get the file path of this image?
>   Also, is there any way I can override the dialog box that pops up and put my own one in?

To achieve the both one way would be to create a new `UITypeEditor`:

```
public class BitmapLocationEditor : UITypeEditor
{

}
```

I overrided the `GetEditStyle`, `EditValue`, `GetPaintvalueSupported` and `PaintValue` methods.

```
// Displays an ellipsis (...) button to start a modal dialog box
public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
{
    return UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal;
}

// Edits the value of the specified object using the editor style indicated by the GetEditStyle method.
public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context,
                                 IServiceProvider provider,
                                 object value)
{
    // Show the dialog we use to open the file.
    // You could use a custom one at this point to provide the file path and the image.
    using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
        openFileDialog.Filter = "Image files (*.bmp | *.bmp;";

        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(openFileDialog.FileName);
            bitmap.SetPath(openFileDialog.FileName);

            return bitmap;
        }
    }

    return value;
}

// Indicates whether the specified context supports painting
// a representation of an object's value within the specified context.
public override bool GetPaintValueSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
{
    return true;
}

// Paints a representation of the value of an object using the specified PaintValueEventArgs.
public override void PaintValue(PaintValueEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Value != null)
    {
        // Get image
        Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)e.Value;

        // This rectangle indicates the area of the Properties window to draw a representation of the value within.
        Rectangle destRect = e.Bounds;

        // Optional to set the default transparent color transparent for this image.
        bmp.MakeTransparent();

        // Draw image
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, destRect);
    }
}
```

Your `Obj` class should remain the same, except add an attribute to take advantage of our new `BitmapLocationEditor` class:

```
public class Obj
{
    private Bitmap myImage;

    [Category("Main Category")]
    [Description("Your favorite image")]
    [Editor(typeof(BitmapLocationEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    public Bitmap MyImage
    {
        get { return myImage; }
        set
        {
            myImage = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The `SetPath` method used in `EditValue` method is just an extension method to set the `Bitmap.Tag` property. You can use later the `GetPath` method to retrieve the actual path of your image file.

```
public static class BitmapExtension
{
    public static void SetPath(this Bitmap bitmap, string path)
    {
        bitmap.Tag = path;
    }

    public static string GetPath(this Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        return bitmap.Tag as string;
    }
}
```

[Article about PropertyGrid](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22717/Using-PropertyGrid)

Comment: Even though I really needed this answer back in January, I still really appreciate this answer. By the way, if you want to know what I needed this for: www.jutanium.com/maze